# How does borane target a specific double bond on an indene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, resonance

[image: indene]

According to the text I am using (Organic Chem, Seyan Ege, 3rd ed, problem 12.57) the halide in the electrophile borane (BH3) binds at site G. But I need to make sure I understand why. First, I believe that the double bond F=G is targeted to begin with because it is the double bond furthest from the electron-withdrawing OR group. Next, why does G get the halide and not F? I believe that is because if F gets the hypothetical positive charge, that charge can be distributed, and there is greater resonance than if the positive charge was localized at G. Is that correct? (Please note I am not a student asking you to do my homework, I am an older person working through the text on my own.)

Comment: Edmund: I'm not sure where halide comes into the picture. Hydroboration is a concerted reaction but not necessarily synchronous. In the transition state the new  G-boron bond is more developed than the F-hydrogen bond. Hence, there is residual positive charge on F as you surmise. This advantage is lost in the regioisomeric transition state. Also recall that $\ce{BH3}$ that boron is more electropositive thathan hydrogen.

Comment: I should also add that the aromatic ring is too stabilized to react with more borane